# split String in Java by auto-incrementing number

Tags: java, string

I want to split a String that looks like this:

```
1. Richard Freitag Ger 370 2. Andreas Wellinger Ger 319 3. Daniel Andre Tande Nor 280 4. Stefan Kraft Aut 212 5. Johann Andre Forfang Nor 205
```

I want to split this text by the index number (1., 2., ...). The output should look something like this:

```
1. Richard Freitag Ger 370
2. Andreas Wellinger Ger 319
... etc...
```

I tried StringTokenizer and loop but its still not working correctly.

Comment: Can you share your StringTokenizer and loop code?

Comment: It'd help if you shared the code you claimed "didn't work"... let's try to figure out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Regex doesn't really have mechanisms to determine if numbers are in order like `1` `2` `3`. It operates more on types of characters (like if it is a digit, or if it is equal to other character). But based on your example you may want to split on *spaces* which has after it *number followed by dot*.

In such case you can use `split("\\s(?=\\d+[.])")`

`(?=...)` is called [look-ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and ensures that regex matched by `...` exist at that position, but it doesn't include it in match, so split will only *consume* whitespace, but will leave *number*.

Demo:

```
String yourText = "1. Richard Freitag Ger 370 2. Andreas Wellinger Ger 319 3. Daniel Andre Tande Nor 280 4. Stefan Kraft Aut 212 5. Johann Andre Forfang Nor 205";
String[] array = yourText.split("\\s(?=\\d+[.])");
for (String text : array){
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Output:

```
1. Richard Freitag Ger 370
2. Andreas Wellinger Ger 319
3. Daniel Andre Tande Nor 280
4. Stefan Kraft Aut 212
5. Johann Andre Forfang Nor 205
```

Answer (score 1):

If the index numbers start from 1 and are continuous, this will give you the expected output:

```
    String input = "1. Richard Freitag Ger 370 2. Andreas Wellinger Ger 319 3. Daniel Andre Tande Nor 280 4. Stefan Kraft Aut 212 5. Johann Andre Forfang Nor 205";
    String[] items = input.split("\\d+\\.");
    for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + i + ". " + items[i]);
    }
```